# Double inner join with 3 tables

Tags: sql, left-join

Update years later:

I came back to answer my own question. I had no idea what an inner join was and apparently completely misused the term here.

---

I currently have the following 3 tables:

**Team**

```
TeamID
```

**Player**

```
PlayerID | TeamID
```

**Match**

```
Player1 | Player2 | Round
```

I want to write a query showing a match like:

```
Team1 | Team2
```

I figured out how to join my tables player and match, so far that works too, but I can't figure out how to replace the player name with the team name. Any idea? I have the following:

```
SELECT P1.PlayerID AS Player1, P2.PlayerID AS Player2
FROM MATCH
INNER JOIN PLAYER AS P1 ON MATCH.Player1 = P1.PlayerID
INNER JOIN PLAYER AS P2 ON MATCH.Player2 = P2.PlayerID
```

Comment: Does table match store a single record for a single match (playerId vs playerId)? So a match is just one on one (like tennis) and not many vs many (like in basketball)?

Comment: A match is 1 vs 1. Put the points get calculated for the team.

Comment: Does `Team1` mean the column TeamID for a single player from table match or do you want to sum all Points from every player of a certain team?

Comment: The points are something I want to add later, for now I just want to have a team overview. Team1 and Team2 indeed mean the TeamID from the table Match

Comment: For a team overview you can do `Select TeamID from Team` ☺, joke aside without a better understanding of what you want it is difficult to help.

Comment: I currently have just what I want. English isn't my first language so it's hard for me to explain what I want.

I wanted an overview of the matches, but with the teamnames instead of the player names, that's it, basically.

I really appreciate the help, by the way :)

Comment: Don't use `DISTINCT`. It should not be necessary in your posted solution, and is too often misused by people who don't understand their data to get rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come back to this question years later.

Assuming the following tables:

**Team**

```
id | name
```

**Player**

```
id | team_id
```

**Match**

```
player1_id | player2_id | round
```

The result I wanted was something like

```
player1's team name | player2's team name | round
```

I used distinct originally, but distinct is not the correct way to remove duplicates, as Turophile correctly points out.

A better query would be something like

```
select t1.name, t2.name, m.round
from match as m
left join player as p1 on m.player1_id = p1.id
left join team as t1 on p1.team_id = t1.id
left join player as p2 on m.player2_id = p2.id
left join team as t2 on p2.team_id = t2.id
```